# Slide the menus on mobile view on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to convert my menus on slider when the menu width is greater then viewport width.

Please don't use any third party plugin just use query for the task.
Be sure when you reach at the end of the menu it stops moving forward and next btn gets disabled, same functionality for prev also.

Here I have added my html, css and jquery can some check this out

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var totalwidth=0;
  $('ul li').each(function(index, el) {
   var liwidth= $(this).outerWidth();
   $(this).css('width', liwidth);
   totalwidth = liwidth + totalwidth ;
   $('ul').css('width', totalwidth);
  });

  var viewwidth = $('.scroll-wrapper').width();
  var navwidth = $('.nav-tabs').width();
  var remainwidth= navwidth - viewwidth;
  var slideval=0;
  

  
  $('.next').on('click',function(){
   if(navwidth >= viewwidth){
    $('.nav').css('transition', '300ms all ease-in-out');
    slideval= viewwidth+slideval;
    var remainslide=remainwidth - slideval;
    $('.nav').css('right',slideval );
   }
  });

  $('.prev').on('click',function(){
    $('.nav').css('transition', '300ms all');
    slideval= viewwidth+slideval;
    $('.nav').css('right',-slideval );
  });
  
 });
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.nav.nav-tabs {
 background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 z-index: 1;
 padding:0;
 /*transition: 0.3s all;*/
}
.nav.nav-tabs > li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
.next,.prev {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 color: red;
 width: 50px;
 height: 17px;
 font-size: 20px;
 right:0;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 99;
}
.prev{
 left:0;
 right:unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
   <li>Shenika Joyal</li>
   <li>Courtney Kingrey</li>
   <li>Donte Magnani bfghfghfghfghfgh</li>
   <li>Tashia Zalenski</li>
   <li>Roxy Cocuzzo</li>
   <li>Rosanna Nette</li>
   <li>Margret Sidhom</li>
   <li>Nena Orsak</li>
   <li>Cassey Yow</li>
   <li>Rachele Gladu</li>
   <li>Dalton Bartash</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow">
   <div class="prev">prev</div>
   <div class="next">next</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.nav.nav-tabs {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  /*transition: 0.3s all;*/
}

.nav.nav-tabs>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.next,
.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 17px;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  right: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>Shenika Joyal</li>
    <li>Courtney Kingrey</li>
    <li>Donte Magnani bfghfghfghfghfgh</li>
    <li>Tashia Zalenski</li>
    <li>Roxy Cocuzzo</li>
    <li>Rosanna Nette</li>
    <li>Margret Sidhom</li>
    <li>Nena Orsak</li>
    <li>Cassey Yow</li>
    <li>Rachele Gladu</li>
    <li>Dalton Bartash</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="prev">prev</div>
    <div class="next">next</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to code it for you? - kinda sounds like it. Got to inform you that this is not how StackOverflow is working. Tell us what is not working with your own attempt, and then we can try help you.

Comment: I agree with @CarstenLøvboAndersen, and what does `just use query for the task` mean?

Comment: @Armel I believe it's a type error, I think it should say `just use jQuery for the task`

Comment: I have modified the code please check @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesss...Implemented this using swiper slider

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       slidesPerView: 4,
       spaceBetween: 1,
       navigation: {
         nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
         prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
       breakpoints: {
         1024: {
           slidesPerView: 4,
           spaceBetween: 1,
         },
         768: {
           slidesPerView: 3,
           spaceBetween: 1,
         },
         640: {
           slidesPerView: 2,
           spaceBetween: 1,
         },
         320: {
           slidesPerView: 1,
           spaceBetween: 1,
         }
       }
     });
   });
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.nav.nav-tabs {
 background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 z-index: 1;
 padding:0;
 /*transition: 0.3s all;*/
}
.nav.nav-tabs > li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css">
<div class="scroll-wrapper swiper-container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs swiper-wrapper"> 
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="active">Natashia</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Daphne</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Brenton</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Gala</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Christen</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">Howard</a></li>
   <li class="swiper-slide"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">Casey</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <h3>HOME</h3>
     <p>Some content.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 1</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menu6" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```